# generate an input file for each map task

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm new with hadoop, and I have the following problem. I want to control the number of mappers, and the simplest way I found is to cheat hadoop into generating an input file for each map task, like in the pi estimator example. So i used the following piece of code:

```
    for(int i=0; i < nMaps; ++i) {
    final Path file = new Path(inDir, "part"+i);
    fs.create(file);
    fs.close();
    }
```

and at compilation there is an error in the fs.create line. Does anyone know what is wrong and how it can be solved? Thanks

Comment: You can set number of map tasks in job configuration.

Comment: The # of map tasks in the job configuration is only a hint and is not used for the # of map tasks for the job. By default, the number of map tasks equals the # of input splits.

Answer (score 0):

You should catch (or rethrow) the `IOException` that might be thrown from [`create`](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#create%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%29) and [`close`](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#close%28%29).